# T-SQL merging two tables with common and uncommon columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

Here is my problem. I have two tables with common and uncommon columns as follows:
Is there an effective way of doing this in T SQL or SSIS?
Thank you

Table 1:

```
a b c
1 2 3
7 8 9
```

Table 2:

```
a d k
4 6 7
9 0 2
```

Merged Table:

```
a   b   c      d    k
1   2   3     null  null
7   8   9     null  null
4 null  null   6    7
9 null  null   0    2
```

Comment: `FULL OUTER JOIN`? [Using the SQL-92 FULL OUTER JOIN syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#d-using-the-sql-92-full-outer-join-syntax)

Comment: What if both tables have the same value for `a`?  What if there are duplicates within a single table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use union  adding null for missing column

```
  select a,b,c, null d, null k
  from table1
  union 
  select a,null, null,d, k
  from table1
```

Comment: This is exactly what I did but I have almost 400 columns to be checked hence trying to find easier solution

Comment: based on sql there is not shortcut .. but could work server side uisng a procedural language  could check  your table schema  select the distinct column  involved  by all the table and build a dinamic sql for 400 table  should be convenient..

Answer (score 2):

You want `FULL OUTER JOIN`, which is available in SQLServer:

```
select coalesce(t1.a, t2.a), t1.b, t1.c t2.d, t2.k
from table1 t1
full outer join table2 t2 on t2.a = t1.a
```

Comment: You'll want `ISNULL(t1.a,t2.a)` here (or `COALESCE`), otherwise the last 2 rows will have a value of `NULL` for `a`, not `4` and `9` respectively.